Capacitor iOS Sync error "While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)"
Running the "npx cap sync ios" command ends with the following error:
<code>L[error] ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory.
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/installer.rb:708:in `verify_gem_home'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/installer.rb:898:in `pre_install_checks'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/installer.rb:303:in `install'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/specification.rb:105:in `install'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:195:in `block in install'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:183:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:183:in `install'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:215:in `install_gem'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:231:in `block in install_gems'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:224:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:224:in `install_gems'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:170:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/command.rb:328:in `invoke_with_build_args'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:253:in `invoke_command'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:193:in `process_args'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:151:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:56:in `run'
/usr/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
</code>

Capacitor 5, macOS 15

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
